# Accidentally i deleted admin user in moodle(phpmyadmin),i cant access anything in siteadministration

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

i cant access site administration without that we cant do any changes,now how to assign admin roles to the new user in the phpmyadmin,if any one know means can u help me out

Comment: Contact your DBA, he might have a daily backup of the DB.

Answer (score 2):

You are going to be messing with the database so be very careful and cautious of what you are doing. It would even be a good idea to make a backup of the database before you begin.

This will involve using phpmyadmin or some other tool that will allow you to access your database. The first thing you want to do is verify that your admin account is truly gone. To do this use phpmyadmin to access your Moodle database. The table you are looking for is more than likely called mdl_user. In this table you should see a user with a user id (first column) of 1 or 2 most likely 2. In the username column you should see an admin username if you didn't change the admin username when you installed your server. If you can't find the user name then it may just be gone. Either way, what you want to take away from this table is the user id for the user that you want to make an admin, that could be you or the admin user account. Remember this id number.

Now find the table called mdl_role. This table shows the various roles that you currently have on your server. More than likely the admin role will have an id (1st column) of 1, but check this table to be sure. Whatever the role id of the admin role is remember this number as well.

Now you need to find the mdl_role_assignments table. This table tracks all of the roles assigned to each individual user by whatever context in which they are assigned. What this means is that for every place in Moodle that you have a role, there will be an entry in this table. For example, lets say I am a teacher in one course, a student in a different course, and I have been given the role of a teacher on a specific activity within the course where I am a student. In this example I would have 3 entries in the role assignments table, one for each of those different roles. A user could have dozens of different roles in this table based on the context where a role has been assigned.

In the userid column of the mdl_role_assignments table find your user or the admin user. There could be multiple entries for this user. Once you find the correct userid, look at the contextid column. You are looking for a contextid of 1. If there is no contexted of 1 then you need to edit one of the existing contextid's so it becomes a 1, with the understanding that you are now removing this user from that existing role and may have to reassign it at a later time. The other option is to just add a new row to the table. Now once you have changed the contextid to a 1 you need to change the roleid to whatever number that corresponds to the admin role id from the mdl_role table mentioned before. Usually this will be a 1 as well. Change the roleid to 1 and save your changes.

This should give you a user that can now function in the admin role.

Source [here](https://moodle.org/mod/forum/discuss.php?d=174230)